# Chaining WCF Async Methods in Silverlight

Tags: c#, wcf, silverlight, asynchronous

I'm developing a silverlight application and consuming WCF service with Async methods. But I couldnt make it working.

In my page I have the code below. Basically I want to first call LoginAsync then GetTablesAsync then GetPlayersAsync and meanwhile I need to call the client notify methods as well. How can I arrange it ? With Locks or is there a method for chaining these events to make sure that they will do fine?

```
public partial class Root : UserControl
{
    private object syncRoot = new object();
    ServiceClient client;

    ObservableCollection<Table> Tables { get; set; }
    ObservableCollection<Player> Players { get; set; }
    public Root()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Tables = new ObservableCollection<Table>();

        txtLogs.Text += "\n";

        client = Helpers.GetServiceClient();

        client.NotifyReceived += new EventHandler<NotifyReceivedEventArgs>(client_NotifyReceived);

        client.PublishCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(client_PublishCompleted);
        client.SubscribeCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(client_SubscribeCompleted);
        client.GetTableListCompleted += client_GetPokerTablesCompleted;



        this.Loaded += Root_Loaded;
    }

    void Root_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        NewUser newUser = new NewUser();
        newUser.Closed += newUser_Closed;
        newUser.Show();
    }

    void newUser_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewUser n = sender as NewUser;
        player = new Player
        {
            PlayerName = n.txtPlayerName.Text,
        };

        lock (syncRoot)
        {

            try
            {
                client.GetTableListAsync();
            }
            catch (TimeoutException ex)
            {

            }
            catch (CommunicationException ex)
            {

            }
        }


        lock (syncRoot)
        {
            client.LoginCompleted += client_LoginCompleted;
            client.LoginAsync(player.PlayerName);
            // publish player logged in
            client.PublishAsync(String.Format("{0} is logged in", player.PlayerName));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found AsyncCTP most useful for the scenario you described. However, you can achieve roughly the same readability as roughly javascript libraries if you use the following pattern:

```
NewUser newUser = new NewUser();
newUser.Show();
newUser.Closed += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
{
    player = new Player
    {
        PlayerName = newUser.txtPlayerName.Text,
    };

    // you aren't going to be able to catch timeout
    // errors in async method calls
    client.GetTableListAsync();

    // we can initiate login even if TableList isn't loaded yet
    client.LoginAsync(player.PlayerName);
    client.LoginCompleted += (s2, e2) => {
        // publish player logged in
        client.PublishAsync(String.Format("{0} is logged in", player.PlayerName));
    }
}
```

Comment: i thik this is the same as my code

Comment: Kubi, you can't chain your code with locks. You need to just call the next routine inside the Completed handler. The code above makes the logic easier to read.

Comment: what I'm thinking was to create a queue for the actions and manage the events. I put locks in my code because of some other thinks in background

Comment: Yes, a queue will work. I've used it successfully before, but I find the alternative easier.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you want to call them one after another?
You could call the second one from the Login completed handler (then the third from the handler for the second one completing etc).

Comment: It works fine (I have this approach in software I've written). You need to add your 'completed' handlers in the same places where you call the web services. (You have the completed handlers in the constructor for the UserControl, but the services aren't called from there.)

Comment: yeah i found out that the reason for that way not working was because of my datacontracts. However, I am syre there are much better ways